# ¿como ocultar o deshabilitar el boton Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-drawerlayout, navigation

Tengo una consulta con respecto al `Navigation Drawer`, al iniciarlo muestra un `Fragment` de Logueo, en el cual quiero que el usuario:

inicia sesion para que se habilite el boton principal de `Navigation Drawer`.

*¿Como deshabilito el boton al iniciar el `Navigation Drawer`?*

*¿como agregar el código para habilitarlo en el botón iniciar sesión del `fragment`?*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo del MainActivity

```
    package com.example.administrador.pruebaws2;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.fragment.IniciarSesionFragment;
    import com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.interfaces.IFragments;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,IFragments { 

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
            /*OCULTA EL BOTON DEL NAVIGATION DRAWER AL INICIAR LA APP*/
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //LLAMO EL FRAGEMENT IniciarSesionFragment EN EL MainActivity     
            Fragment miFragment=new IniciarSesionFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Content_Main_Fragment,miFragment).commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }   
        @Override
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        }
    }
```

Esto es lo contiene el Content main y donde muestro el fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/content_main">

<!-- donde muestro el fragment iniciar sesion -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Content_Main_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Este es el fragmen IniciarSesionFragment en el boton btnIniciarSesion solo estoy cerrando el fragment y habilitando el boton Navigation Drawer

```
    package com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.fragment;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.R;
    import com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.entidades.VolleySingleton;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.HashMap;


    public class IniciarSesionFragment extends Fragment {

        private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

        public static final String TAG= IniciarSesionFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        EditText txtnombre, txtcedula;
        TextView tv_registrarse;
        Button btnIniciarSesion;
        DrawerLayout drawer; Toolbar toolbar;


        //PERMITE HACER LA CONEXION CON EL SERVIDOR
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        StringRequest stringRequest;

        public IniciarSesionFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_iniciar_sesion, container, false);

            txtnombre= vista.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            txtcedula=vista.findViewById(R.id.txtCedula);

            tv_registrarse=vista.findViewById(R.id.tv_registrarse);

            btnIniciarSesion=vista.findViewById(R.id.btnIniciarSesion);
    //BOTON iniciar Sesion
           btnIniciarSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
//CIERRO EL FRAGMETN
                   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                            remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Content_Main_Fragment)).commit();
    //SEGUN SE ACTIVARIA EL DrawerNavigation
                    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                            getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
                    toggle.syncState();
                }
            });

            return vista;
        }

        private void mIniciarSesion() {
            String ip=getString(R.string.ip);
            String url=ip+"/iniciarSesion.php?nombre="+txtnombre.getText().toString()+"&cedula="+txtcedula.getText().toString();
            url=url.replace(" ","%20");

            // Obtener valores actuales de los controles
         *  final String nombre = txtnombre.getText().toString();
            final String cedula = txtcedula.getText().toString();

            // Mapeo previo
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("nombre", nombre);
            map.put("cedula", cedula);

            // Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
            JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);

            // Depurando objeto Json...
            Log.d(TAG,"CONTENEDOR_jobjetct"+ jobject.toString());

            VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(
                   new JsonObjectRequest(
                           Request.Method.GET, url, null,

                           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                   procesarRespuesta(response);
                                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),"RESPEUSTA_TOAS="+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               }
                           },
                           new Response.ErrorListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                   Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),"error_volley="+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                               }
                           }
                   )
           );
        }

        private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

           try {
           //    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("estado");
               String estado= response.getString("estado");
                switch (estado){

                    case "1":
                      //  Log.i(TAG,"IMPRIMIR_RESPONSE="+response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"RESPEUSTA_TOAS="+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        //  Log.i(TAG,"IMPRIMIR_RESPONSE="+response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"RESPEUSTA_TOAS="+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        //  Log.i(TAG,"IMPRIMIR_RESPONSE="+response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"RESPEUSTA_TOAS="+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static IniciarSesionFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            IniciarSesionFragment fragment = new IniciarSesionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {

            }
        }

        // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mListener = null;
        }

        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            // TODO: Update argument type and name
            void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para deshabilitar el Navigation Drawer puedes usar el método [setDrawerLockMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode(int)) de tu `DrawerLayout`:

```
myDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

para volver a habilitarlo usa :

```
myDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

---

Para habilitarlo al iniciar sesión agrega un listener a tu botón, ejemplo

```
Button btnIniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIniciar);

    btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo Jorgesys. pues me funciona el codigo. pero creo q se me olvido decir que al abrirse el _Navigation Drawer_ lo que muestro de entrada en el _MainActivity_ mando a llamar un fragment.el codigo me funciona el que deshabilita el boton.en el _onCreate_ del _MainActivity_ el que me cierra la aplicacin es el que hago desde el fragment. como aplicar desde el boton del fragment *Iniciar sesion* utilizar el codigo para habilitar el boton del _Navigation Drawer_

Comment: Saludos Jorgesys. el ejemplo que pones todo lo hago realize prubas desde el MaintActivity al ejecutarlo esta deshabilitado,cree un botonen esa activity lo habilita. pero en mi caso COMO puedo utilizar este metodo `myDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);  en el fragment que se carga en esa actividad.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, de acuerdo a lo que he leído en tu pregunta, y en el comentario de la respuesta de de Jorgesys, me parece que lo que necesitas hacer es algo como esto, explicare todo paso por paso.

1) Como se sabe, para mostrar el botón que se usa para abrir el `DrawerNavigation` se implementan las siguientes 3 lineas de código:

```
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

2) Ya con esto tenemos visible el botón y el comportamiento del mismo, en este caso abrir | cerrar el `Drawer`, bien, importante resaltar este botón es mostrado en el `toolbar / ActionBar`, por ende para controlar que el mismo no este visible, solo tendríamos que usar lo siguiente:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

3) De esta forma ya el botón no seria visible, pero de que manera podría emplear ambas formas para ocultar o mostrar el botón según la necesidad que tenga, bueno, un ejemplo de como hacerlo podría ser el siguiente, teniendo en cuenta que estas manejando el cambio de `fragments` en toda la pantalla, o por decirlo de otra forma, el espacio restante después del `toolbar`:

```
LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, loginFragment,getClass().getName())
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

4) Suponiendo que al momento en que haces uso de tu "`container`" por así decirlo (Actividad que controla el cambio y vistas de `fragments` - contenedor de los mismos), tendrás algo como el código anterior, donde seteas la vista del fragmento `login` al abrir la `app`, bien, las lineas de abajo serian para mostrar tu botón del `Drawer`, pero como en tu caso no quieres que sea visible, lo que se haría es lo siguiente:

```
LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, loginFragment,getClass().getName())
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

5) De esta manera tendrías seteada tu vista de `Login` sin el botón del `Drawer`, ahora, cuando el usuario y la contraseña son validos, es necesario mostrar el `Drawer`, de que forma se haría?, así:

```
if (Login exitoso){

MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mainFragment,getClass().getName())
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

}
```

5.1) Acá ya tendrías tu segundo `fragment` cargado, o en caso de ser un `Activity` lo que se cargará después del `Login`, solo con un `intent`, así:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Activity.this, SegundaActivity.class)
 startActivity(intent);
```

Y en el `onCreate` del otro `Activity`, llamarías el botón del `Drawer` tal cual como en el paso "1".

6) Bien llegados a este paso, si quieres hacer un `Logout`, saliendo de tu `Activity`, o segundo `fragment`, de nuevo a tu `Login`, pero claro, tendrías que ocultar de nuevo el botón del `Drawer`, ya que este no debe verse en el `Login`, bien, si el `Logout` lo haces desde la acción de un botón, dentro de tu `onClick` harías algo así:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (SegundaActivity.this, LoginActivity.class)
 startActivity(intent);
```

Y al momento de llegar al otro `Activity`(`Login`), como en el `onCreate` de tu primer `Activity` (`Login`), definiste:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

El botón del `Drawer` no se verá.

Creo que me extendí mucho pero quería tratar de ser lo mas explicito y claro posible, pero lo mas importante de este ejemplo es el manejo de mostrar y ocultar el botón para abrir el `Drawer`, y tener en cuenta como ocultarlo y mostrarlo, y muy importante, donde?, cómo?, de acuerdo a si es un `Activity` o un `Fragment`.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempor David Villagas, por tu respuesta, le metere la mano al codigo para hacer las pruebas que necesito. cual quier coso te comento si en algo no llego a entender. Saludos

Comment: Excelente, estaré por acá @novatophp2014

Comment: en el onCreate del MainActivity  despues del codigo donde se inicializa el 'DrawerNavigation' agregue el 'toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);' al ejecutar la app el boton esta oculto todo bien.en elboton de logueo del fragment agrege lo que indicas en el punto#5 declare las variables 'DrawerLayout drawer; Toolbar toolbar;' xq me daba error. ago clic _iniciar seseion_ y se cierra la app.

Comment: Cuando das clic al botón de Login... Qué cargas si el Login es exitoso? otro fragment? o otro activity?

Comment: ok me explico, en el MainActivity muestro un fragment.este contiene un formulario de logueo y el boton iniciar sesion como se muestra arriba en la imagen.la logica seria si el logeo es exitoso o al confirmar que el usuario existe en la bd,se cierrra solamente el fragment y se activa o se hace visible el boton del _DrawerNavigation_. si quieres te muestro el codigo de como esta la aplicacion para q tengas una mejor idea.

Comment: Que error te sale? por que al momento de cambiar de un `fragment` a otro, de `login` a `home` por decirlo así, el paso 5 debería ser el correcto, estas manejando bien el uso del `Toolbar`?

Comment: como te dije se cierra la aplicaino en los log me muestra el siguietne error02-22 11:17:46.845 10893-10893/com.example.administrador.pruebaws2 E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.administrador.pruebaws2, PID: 10893
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.administrador.pruebaws2.fragment.IniciarSesionFragment$1.onClick(IniciarSesionFragment.java:77)
 justo en el fragement iniciarsesion dentro del boton btnIniciarSesion en el onClick

Comment: Ya vi cual es tu problema, recuerda que el `Toolbar` esta en la actividad, el `fragment` solo es una pequeña porción de vista, dentro de la actividad, el manejo de mostrar y ocultar el botón de `drawer` se hace en la actividad, no en el `fragment`, por eso decía al final de mi respuesta, que dependiendo de que estés haciendo, si cargas otro `fragment` solo llamas el `drawer` a penas hagas el cambio de `fragment`,  ya que técnicamente, sigues en la misma actividad, solo que mostrando una porción de vista diferente.

Comment: y en este caso que es lo mas recomendable hacer.

Comment: Como te lo detalle en la respuesta, haces el cambio de un `fragment` por otro, y muestras el `Drawer`, como te dije antes, debes entender que es un [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es-419) para poder hacer buen uso de el.

Comment: ok en el boton iniciarsesion agrege el siguiente codigo y se cierra la app `FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.replace(R.id.Content_Main_Fragment, new BienvenidoFragment());
trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
trans.commit();` la verdad no se que estoy aciendo mal. esto seria para reemplazar el fragment `iniciarsesiongrament` y se agrege `Bienvenidofrment`

Answer (score 0):

Jorgesys  -  David Villegas 
gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder y tambien por no hacerlo ya que eso me lleva a investigar mas.

en el onCreate agrege una sola linea, la cual hace que se deshabilite el boton.

y declare la variable de esta manera

```
 final public static DrawerLayout drawer = null;


 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();
    //ESTA LINEA            
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Luego creo un metodo en el cual contiene lo mismo pero al final elcodigo que habilita el boton del DrawerNavigation

```
public void Drawerr() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    }
```

investigando algunas respuestas encontre como llamar ese metodo estando en un fragment y eso fue lo que ise desde el fragment habilitarlo.

```
btnIniciarSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

  mIniciarSesion();

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.root_frame)).commit();

            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).Drawerr();
          }
        });
```

Solo tengo una consulta, quiero saber si estoy aplicando bien el llamado del metodo.